# Why does ModalPopupExtender not show through javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I followed several web resources to understand how to show a popup from client side, and I made this code:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnOk" ImageUrl="imagens/btnAlterar.gif" OnClientClick="btnOkClick()" />

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="dummyForPopup" Visible="false"/>

<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" BehaviorID="btnOkPopupBehavior" ID="MPXtender" TargetControlID="dummyForPopup"  PopupControlID="pnlUpdateUserModal" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnCloseRequestUserUpdate" OnOkScript="userUpdReq_onOk()" />


function btnOkClick()
{
    if(validateAll())
    {
        var behavior = $find('btnOkPopupBehavior');
        if (behavior)
        {
            behavior.show();
        }
        else
        {
            var lblOutput = $get('<%= lblOutput .ClientID %>');
            lblOutput .innerText = 'Couldn't find popup';
        }
    }
}
```

previously I had the modal popup linked to the ok button, it was working pretty well. Now I need some validation before opening the popup, and this code is not working anylonger =/

Comment: thanks a lot buddy.. because of u i solved my problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Your dummy button has to be visible = true, otherwise the javascript doesn't work properly. So set visible = true but disaply none with css:

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server"
 ID="dummyForPopup" style
 ="display:none" Visible="true" />
```

2) lblOutput .innerText = 'Couldn't find popup'; is a javascript error. You need to change it to: "Couldn't find popup"; (or use `&apos;`)

3) OnClientClick="btnOkClick()" should really say: OnClientClick="btnOkClick(); return false;"

4) Look for any other javascript errors on your page because those will stop the popup from workign properly.